# виснет программа

Tags: qt, winapi

Здравствуйте, пишу отладчик под windows, использую winapi и qt, написал цикл обработки сообщений отладки, он стандартный:

```
DEBUG_EVENT debug_event = {0};
for(;;) 
{
    if (!WaitForDebugEvent(&debug_event, INFINITE))
        return;
    ProcessDebugEvent(&debug_event);  // User-defined function, not API
    ContinueDebugEvent(debug_event.dwProcessId,
                  debug_event.dwThreadId,
                  DBG_CONTINUE);
}
```

но с ним программа виснет, скажите пожалуйста что надо добавить в этот цикл, чтобы главное окно приложения не подвисало, заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте: `QApplication::processEvents()`

Comment: Вставил в цикл `QApplication::processEvents()` (без параметров), присоединяююсь к процессу (калькулятор) - программа  работает как-то странно - то отвечает, то нет.

Comment: В общем, не помогло(

Comment: Пробовал и `qApp->processEvents()`

Comment: Кст, а какая прога виснет? Которую отлаживаете? Меня смущает этот бесконечный цикл, может его возможно в поток вынести?

Comment: Нет, виснет отладчик.

Comment: Причем поначалу, если не делать никаких действий с отлаживаемой программой, отладчик работает нормально (меняются регистры и пр.), но как только сделаешь что-нибудь с отлаживаемой программой, отладчик виснет.

Comment: Если нужен еще какой-нибудь код, могу выложить.